# dynamic python class with partial function

Tags: python, dynamic

print(I'm puzzled by what appears to be a bug in python3.

I want to create a class dynamically with some class methods. I seem to be able to do it like this:

```py
import types

def class_body(ns):
    ns.update({"a": lambda self, x: x - 1})
    return ns

newc = types.new_class("foo", exec_body=class_body)

print(newc().a(3))

# prints 2 as expected
```

But I also want to create the class methods dynamically. I seem to be able to do something like:

```py
import types
def funcs_gen(k=1):
    def fn(self, a):
        return a + k + self.i
    return fn

def class_body(ns):
    ns.update({"a": funcs_gen(k=2), "i": 5})
    return ns

newc = types.new_class("foo", exec_body=class_body)

print(newc().a(1))

# prints 8 as expected
```

But something weird seems to happen if I try to do the same with partial functions:

```py
import types
from functools import partial

def fn(self, a, k=1):
    return a + k + self.i

def class_body(ns):
    ns.update({"a": partial(fn, k=2), "i": 5})
    return ns

newc = types.new_class("foo", exec_body=class_body)

print(newc().a(1))

# Unexpectedly produces: `TypeError: fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'`
```

Comment: change `def fn(self, a ...`  -> `def fn(a ... `

Comment: Sure, but in my real implementation I what if I want to access some class data.

Comment: or use [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) instead for class methods

Comment: I edited the example to better show the problem

Comment: partialmethod works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Because `partial` objects do not implement the descriptor protocol to bind the instance as the first argument to itself. As an aside, note that `types.new_class` is a just a convienience function, you can also just use `type` directly, which takes `type(name, bases, namespace)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) for methods.

```
import types
from functools import partialmethod

def fn(self, a, k=1):
    return a + k + self.i

def class_body(ns):
    ns.update({"a": partialmethod(fn, k=2), "i": 5})
    return ns

newc = types.new_class("foo", exec_body=class_body)

print(newc().a(1))
```

**output:**

```
8
```